# How to use an aggregate function on a sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven't found an answer to this on similar questions. How can I use an aggregate function on a sub query like,

when I query a table called ratioPnLTable in my datatbase like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT strat_id, ratio, root FROM ratioPnltable
WHERE totalPnl IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(TotalPnl) FROM ratioPnlTable
GROUP BY strat_id)
```

I get this results:

```
strat_id ratio  root
  1        2.6    AD
  1        2.7    AD
  1        2.8    AD
  2        1.4    ED
  2        1.5    ED
  2        1.6    ED
  3        1.9    HG
  3        2.0    HG
  3        2.1    HG
```

Instead I would like to have the minimum value only of ratio like this:

```
strat_id ratio  root
  1        2.6    AD
  2        1.4    ED
  3        1.9    HG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this just be a MIN() statement?  Unless the Root can be different..

```
SELECT 
    strat_id,
    MIN(ratio) ratio,
    root
FROM
    ratioPnltable
WHERE
    totalPnl IN (query)
GROUP BY
    strat_id,
    root
```

Comment: This is Answer works because I plug in the sub query with the maximum values of TotalPnL

Comment: And no there is only one Root possible for each Strat_ID

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample results, you can do what you want with `row_number()` and no aggregation at all:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by strat_id order by ratio) as seqnum
      from ratioPnltable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This should have better performance then the other solutions.

Comment: But I lost my previous filter retaining only the maximum value in TotalPnL, so it does not work (Sorry I previously wrote that comment above)